# Objective-C: how to group a series of string constants?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I defined a series of string constants like below, in macro way,

```
#define EXT_RESULT_APPID  @"appid"
#define EXT_RESULT_ERROR_CODE  @"errorcode"
#define EXT_RESULT_PROGRESS  @"progress"
...
```

All these constants are supposed to be used in same context, so **I'd like to constraint them in a same namespace, and I don't want to make them global**, just like what this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653320/how-are-string-constants-in-objective-c-stored-retrieved) said.

In the other hand, I could put all numeric constants in an enum but it doesn't work for strings.
Then how could I group these related string constants?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's one approach:

**MONExtResult.h**

```
// add __unsafe_unretained if compiling for ARC
struct MONExtResultStruct {
    NSString * const AppID;
    NSString * const ErrorCode;
    NSString * const Progress;
};

extern const struct MONExtResultStruct MONExtResult;
```

**MONExtResult.m**

```
const struct MONExtResultStruct MONExtResult = {
    .AppID = @"appid",
    .ErrorCode = @"errorcode",
    .Progress = @"progress"
};
```

In use:

```
NSString * str = MONExtResult.AppID;
```

Comment: is this solution correct and will not cause any memory leaks? will be always those strings retained/not nill?

Comment: @user969153 like `static NSString* const SomeConstant = @"SomeConstant";`, the string is immortal.

Comment: If you just want to use the struct/strings within a single class/m file Is there anyway to do this without having to declare the variables and define their values seperately? (To save typing boilerplate)

Answer (score 0):

Create a header file where you declare your strings and import it when needed

Comment: You mean a header file which contains all constants? I already did so, but I don't think it's for my purpose

Comment: why not? you can include them in the specific context and be done with it

Answer (score 0):

You may create a header file name "Constants.h". Then you need to import this header file where you want to use these constants like:

```
#import "Constants.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a header file say `Constants.h`

Add all constants in this file. These can be constants that you would like to use in deferent classes of your project.

```
#define EXT_RESULT_APPID  @"appid"
#define EXT_RESULT_ERROR_CODE  @"errorcode"
#define EXT_RESULT_PROGRESS  @"progress"
```

Now, instead of importing this `Constants.h` in every class, goto `<project name>-Prefix.pch` file and import the File here.

```
#import "SCConstants.h"
```

now you can use the Constants in any class of the project to your ease.