# Prevent takeRetainedValue or takeUnretainedValue when using an Objective-C Struct

Tags: objective-c, c, swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313448/35690) to keep my string constants together. Using the same example from that post:

**MONExtResult.h**

```
struct MONExtResultStruct {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString * const AppID;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString * const ErrorCode;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString * const Progress;
};

extern const struct MONExtResultStruct MONExtResult;
```

**MONExtResult.m**

```
const struct MONExtResultStruct MONExtResult = {
    .AppID = @"appid",
    .ErrorCode = @"errorcode",
    .Progress = @"progress"
};
```

This can be used in Objective-C like so:

```
NSString *str = MONExtResult.AppID;
```

When I try to use it in Swift, however:

```
let appID: String = MONExtResult.AppID
```

... I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Unmanaged<NSString>!' to expected argument type 'String'

This is because I need to grab the value from the [unmanaged wrapper](http://nshipster.com/unmanaged/) and then convert it to a String:

```
let appID: String = MONExtResult.AppID.takeUnretainedValue() as String
```

Is there any way to annotate the objective-C code to prevent the need for calling `takeUnretainedValue` like you can with `CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED` or `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED` for C functions?

**Update:** The constants must be accessible by both Objective-C and Swift. Otherwise I would just use a Swift enum with `String` raw value.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I was able to construct is this:

```
enum MONExtResult: String {
    case AppID = "com.me.myapp"
    case ErrorCode = "game over"
    case Progress = "vote Tuesday"
}

extension String {
    init(const: MONExtResult) {
        self = const.rawValue
    }
}

let err = String(MONExtResult.ErrorCode)
```

It's worth noting that this doesn't work:

```
let appID: String = MONExtResult.AppID
```

for lack of .rawValue at the end, but so long as you're willing to accept roughly the same number of characters and a slightly different syntax, I believe this does what you had in mind.

Comment: One of the requirements is that it must remain an Objective-C struct, since I need to use it both in Objective-C and Swift. If I create the enum in Swift, it isn't accessible in Objective-C code because of the raw value.

Comment: Please give me an example of how you want to use it Objective-C

Comment: Also, what happens if you simply eliminate all of the unsafe unretained annotations?

Comment: I updated the example to show how it's used in Objective-C (`MONExtResult.AppID`).