# ObjC ternary operator and const strings

Tags: objective-c, casting, constants

If you have a static const string, then its usage may cause inconsistent interpretation by the compiler. For example in this case:

```
const NSString* kUntitled = @"Untitled";

NSString* title = kUntitled;
```

the compiler will complain about assigning a const pointer to a non-const one ("discards qualifiers") and probably rightly so. This can be solved by either not using `const` at all, or by invoking `kUntitled.copy` (I somehow don't like the idea of typecasting `(NSString*)kUntitled`)

However, if you have instead:

```
NSString* title = aTitle ?: kUntitled;
```

then the compiler doesn't complain.

My first question is, can the warning be ignored in the first example? Are there any potential dangers in assigning a const NSString to a non-const one?

Second is, why does the compiler ignore the case with the ternary operator?

Comment: You could also do this: `NSString const * title = kUntitled;`. I would personally not ignore any warning. The second case might be just a limitation of the compiler itself.

Comment: In my case `title` is a member and I can't declare it const. In fact there is rarely any point in assigning one const to another.

Comment: Assigning a const to another const makes perfect sense within a method. But in your case I would just copy the string.

Comment: Assigning one const to another will be discarded by any decent optimizing compiler because it never makes any sense from that perspective, except when you have conditional compilation and you want some readability.

Comment: Telling compiler that a value is constant is always a good practice and could lead to better performance. Not only with conditional compilation. You can have conditional behaviour without conditional compilation, obviously. For example: `NSString * const url = useMainServer ? url1 : url2;` when both url1 and url2 are const.

Comment: @Adam ok good point ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the Weird and Wonderful World of C Declarations - the stuff of quiz questions ;-)

> ```
> const NSString* kUntitled = @"Untitled";
> ```

You probably haven't written what you intended here. This defines `kUntitled` to be a *mutable* pointer to a "constant" string - usually referred to as a "pointer to a constant"... However it's "constant" for a reason as despite the common "pointer to a constant" it is actually a "read-only pointer" meaning you can read but *not write* via the pointer, what is pointed at might well be mutable but it is not mutable via this point if so...

Confused? What the above all means is that you can later write:

```
kUntitled = @"oops you probably thought you couldn't assign";
```

As the pointer itself is mutable, it can be changed to point at other things.

What you probably intended was:

```
NSString * const kUntitled = @"Untitled";
```

which declares a *constant pointer to a string* - it is the *pointer* itself which cannot be changed so:

```
kUntitled = @"this will produce a compile error, can't change a constant";
```

If you use this version of the declaration then you won't get an error on your assignments:

> ```
> NSString* title = kUntitled;
> NSString* title = aTitle ?: kUntitled;
> ```

However that still leaves the question of why you didn't get an error from the second with your original declaration...

The RHS of the assignment, `aTitle ?: kUntitled` is actually valid, the weird world of C again. This expression is just shorthand for `aTitle ? aTitle : kUntitled` and the rules for this operator in C state that the second and third arguments can be of the same base pointer type, `NSString *` in your case, but *differ* in qualifiers, `const` in your case, and the resultant type is the base pointer type with *all* the qualifiers of the two operands.

In other words the result of this expression is treated as `const NSString *`. Which means you should get the same warning as for the first assignment.

It appears that the compiler is treating the operator as though the resultant type is the base pointer type with *none or only the common qualifiers* of the two operands - i.e. the *opposite* of the definition.

So for the second problem you may have found a compiler bug, you should report it to Apple (bug reporter.apple.com) and see what they say.

HTH

Comment: Nice coverage of the type rules for the ternary conditional operator! I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is a side effect of the fact that `const NSString * kUntitled` is incorrect. This is a declaration of a pointer-to-readonly-`NSString`. Note the placement of the "read only" there -- it's referring to the *string*, not the pointer. But ObjC objects are never read only, never `const`. You may say that literal `NSString`s *are*, of course, but that's [implementation dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654036/603977), and even modifiable in some runtime environments.

Thus you can never correctly assign this object anywhere else (unless that variable also was a pointer to a `const` object).

The declaration that you should be using is `NSString * const kUntitled` -- this is "readonly-pointer-to-`NSString`", i.e., the *pointer* cannot be changed to point at another object.